# OfficeJS : To , CC email order not picked up correctly

Tags: office-js

Adding the emails in the to/cc list in the Desktop client is not picked up in correct order. Typing the emails sequentially gets picked up correctly . However using a copy paste of emails into specific positions (like position 1 in the to list) does not get honoured by Office JS.

Scenario : Adding email ids in the to cc list using copy paste of email id.
1. Add emailId (abcd@microsoft.com) at position 1.( TO : abcd@microsoft.com)
2. Invoke the outlook addin.
3. Read the emails Ids in the to / cc list work properly.
4. copy paste an emailId into position 1 in to list(TO : pqrs@microsoft.com; abcd@microsoft.com)
5. Re-invoke the outlook addin
6. Read the emailIds in the to / cc list is able to identify the emails , however the order in which they are present in the to/cc list is not maintained .

[Emails entered in to list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOcKy.png)
[Order of data in JS array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUcOf.png)

When we read the JS array where the to items are stored we get the emailId pqrs@microsoft.com is present at position 2 and abcd@microsoft.com at position 1.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on Office JS API object [Recipients](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Recipients.html) has no mention about order of the array of EmailAddressDetails objects. In fact you may read that "SetAsync" method overwrites the current recipient list with new one. This means you cannot relay on order of the recipients and should be working with e-mail addreses (EmailAddressDetails object) instead. it should not be very difficult to handle actual e-mail addresses or EmailAddressDetails objects and do not look at the position inside the recipients array. Hope this is what you asked for.